# General question regarding n_components in UMAP and the resulting plot

Tags: machine-learning, python

Lets say we define n_components in UMAP to be 5 (or really any number greater than 2). When we plot the result in 2D, what features are being displayed? Does UMAP identify the features with the most information? If so, how? Does it choose the features randomly? Or does it project the 5D result again into a 2D space?

Answer (score -1):

UMAP (Uniform Manifold Approximation and Projection) is a dimensionality reduction algorithm that is typically used to reduce high-dimensional data down to 2 or 3 dimensions so that it can be visualized. When you set the value of n_components to 5 in UMAP, you are telling the algorithm to reduce the data down to 5 dimensions. This does not necessarily mean that the resulting plot will have 5 distinct features or dimensions.

When UMAP projects the high-dimensional data down to a lower-dimensional space, it does not choose the features with the most information or project them randomly. Instead, it uses a combination of methods, including local linear embedding and a novel technique called "stochastic gradient descent on a Riemannian manifold," to preserve the structure of the data as much as possible while reducing its dimensionality. This means that the resulting plot will typically retain the most important features and relationships in the data, even if it doesn't perfectly preserve all of the original dimensions.

If you want to see the 5-dimensional result of the UMAP reduction, you will need to use a different visualization technique, such as a parallel coordinates plot, that can display more than two or three dimensions at once. Alternatively, you can try using a different dimensionality reduction algorithm that is better suited to preserving higher-dimensional structure, such as t-SNE.

Comment: Hi. I think we're talking past each other a bit, so let me clarify what my question is. I do know that UMAP isn't able to visualize more than 3 features at a time in one plot (then again, what algorithm is^^). But for the sake of this example, lets talk about a single 2-D plot. What if you choose n_components (meaning the dimensionality of your low-dimensional feature space) to be something bigger than 2? Lets say n_components = 5. UMAP is still able to plot the corresponding 2-D feature space.

Comment: That means however, that it has to choose _somehow_ what features to plot from the pre-defined 5-D low dimensional feature space. Either it does this by doing something as simple as taking randomly two features and ploth them; or it somehow finds the features with the most information (think of explained variance ratio in PCA); or it (for example) projects the samples from 5-D again into 2-D in order to plot them. And that's exactly what I'm interested in. _How_ does UMAP solve this in reality.

Comment: Lastly, I'd like to argue against your last statement. Theoretically, UMAP is better suited to handle high-dimensional data in comparison to t-SNE. If you're interested in why, then read this pretty cool [blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-exactly-umap-works-13e3040e1668). In fact, I'm pretty sure you have to use something like Autoencoders or PCA to perform a pre-dimensionality reduction before you're able to plug really high-dimensional data into t-SNE in order to get a sensible result.